# .htaccess rewrite multiple parameters

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, uri

I try to rewrite my URLs from `domain.tld/?country=XX&admin1=YY&city=ZZ` to `domain.tld/XX/YY/ZZ`

I have tried

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z]{2,2})/(.*)/(.*)$ /?country=$1&admin1=$2&city=$3 [QSA]
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have these rules in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?country=([^\s&]+)&admin1=([^\s&]+)&city=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ /?country=$1&admin1=$2&city=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This worked for rewriting the URI. But now the site crashed because all included files like images are rewritten to `domain.tld/XX/YY/some/image/source`. Any suggestions?

Comment: That is due to use of relative paths for images/css/js. To fix you can add this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current page's URL.

Comment: This worked for images (<img> elements), but not for javascript (<script> elements) and css (<link> elements). What about `RewriteBase` in htaccess?

Comment: No `<base>` tag affects css/js also. You are better off using absolute URL  rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.